# Focusing subsequent fields with a single JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html

Noob here..I am trying to auto-focus fields based on a criterion that when a field contains a predefined length of input, it must automatically focus the next field.

```html
<html>
<body>
 <input type="number" id="box1" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup='checkInput()'> - <input type="number" id="box2"onkeyup='checkInput()'> - <input type="number" id="box3"onkeyup='checkInput()'>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkInput(){
   if(parseInt(document.getElementById('box1').value.length) == 3)
    document.getElementById('box2').focus();
  }



 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can always write that many functions and manually pick the next field. But is there a way to do it with just JS function, by passing `this.id` to as the argument to that function?

Comment: `onkeyup='checkInput(this)'` and then adapt the function to use this.

Comment: `document.getElementById('box1').value.length` returns a number; no need to `parseInt` on the value.

Comment: Noted....Thanks @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `id` of the current input element to the `checkInput()` function and As you are doing it in plain javaScript and not using `jQuery`, You can use the [**nextElementSibling**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp) property to get the next element and then focus on it using `.focus()` as shown below :

```js
function checkInput(id) {
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value.length) == 3)
      var nextSibling = document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling;
    if (nextSibling) {
      nextSibling.focus();
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="numbers" id="box1" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup='checkInput("box1")'>-
  <input type="numbers" id="box2" onkeyup='checkInput("box2")'>-
  <input type="numbers" id="box3" onkeyup='checkInput("box3")'>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I just answered it and I'm updating it with the explanation.

Comment: Good answers have both, at the same time. Please stop trying so hard to be the first to answer and instead try to have the best answer. That's the way to get more upvotes.

Comment: Working fine. Thanks for introducing me to a cool prop :) @suzo

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Nothing like that, Thanks for the suggestion, I just added the snippet first, tested it and then started explaining it. Ultimately we all want to help the OP  gets solved with the best solution :)

Comment: @CoderSenju: Good to know that and No problem, Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to select all inputs and then select the next input when length greater than 3.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('input').on('keyup',(event)=>{
      console.log(event.target.value.length);
      if(event.target.value.length == 3){
        $(event.target).next().focus();
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
 <input type="numbers" id="box1" autofocus="autofocus" > - <input type="numbers" id="box2"> - <input type="numbers" id="box3">

</body>
</html>
```